# Getting intellisense working in Visual Studio 2015 for javascript function expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I have seen examples in Visual Studio 2015 where you can get intellisense working for JavaScript function declarations, as documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt162307.aspx

So for example:

```
/** @description Determines the area of a circle that has the specified radius parameter.
 * @param {number} radius The radius of the circle.
 * @return {number}
 */
function getArea(radius) {
    var areaVal;
    areaVal = Math.PI * radius * radius;
    return areaVal;
}
```

Give us

[image]

What I would like to know is if it is possible to get this working for functions where the function is assigned to a variable

```
 /** @description Determines the area of a circle that has the specified radius parameter.
 * @param {number} radius The radius of the circle.
 * @return {number}
 */
var getArea = function(radius) {
    var areaVal;
    areaVal = Math.PI * radius * radius;
    return areaVal;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work and when working on an Angular JS project where a lot of funcitons are declared like `$scope.something = function()` it would be very useful.

Anybody know of a way to do get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having a closer look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Intellisense/.